How do I breakdown a singular line of data in a LineChart
I have a line chart I use to display data and one of the lines in my line chart is called "Other" which is a bunch of different smaller data combined into one singular line. When I hover the data I want to be able to see the breakdown of the data in the legend, but I'm not sure how to properly carry this out.
Here the following code has other which is a sum of problem, problem_task, incident_task, u_incident_task, cert_task, cert_follow_on_task, sysapproval_group. I successfully can manipulate these data into a combined other.
    this._AnalyticService.Tickets$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
      .subscribe((response) => {
        if (response) {
          let incidents: number[] = [];
          let changeTasks: number[] = [];
          let monthTotal: number[] = [];
          let monthYear: string[] = [];
          let other: number[] = [];
          let problem_task: number[] = [];
          let incident_task: number[] = [];
          let u_incident_task: number[] = [];
          let cert_task: number[] = [];
          let cert_follow_on_task: number[] = [];
          let sysapproval_group: number[] = [];
    
          for (let val in response) {
            incidents.push(response[val]["incident"] ?? 0);
            changeTasks.push(response[val]["change_task"] ?? 0);
            monthTotal.push(response[val]["total"] ?? 0);
            monthYear.push(response[val]["year_month"] ?? '');
    
            problem_task.push(response[val]["problem_task"] ?? 0);
            incident_task.push(response[val]["incident_task"] ?? 0);
            u_incident_task.push(response[val]["u_incident_task"] ?? 0);
            cert_task.push(response[val]["cert_task"] ?? 0);
            cert_follow_on_task.push(response[val]["cert_follow_on_task"] ?? 0);
            sysapproval_group.push(response[val]["sysapproval_group"] ?? 0);
    
            const otherSum =
              (response[val]["problem"] ?? 0) +
              (response[val]["problem_task"] ?? 0) +
              (response[val]["incident_task"] ?? 0) +
              (response[val]["u_incident_task"] ?? 0) +
              (response[val]["cert_task"] ?? 0) +
              (response[val]["cert_follow_on_task"] ?? 0) +
              (response[val]["sysapproval_group"] ?? 0);
    
            other.push(otherSum);
          }
    
          this.TicketLineChartData.datasets[0].data = monthTotal;
          this.TicketLineChartData.datasets[1].data = incidents;
          this.TicketLineChartData.datasets[2].data = other;
          this.TicketLineChartData.datasets[3].data = changeTasks;
    
          this.problem_task = problem_task;
          this.incident_task = incident_task;
          this.u_incident_task = u_incident_task;
          this.cert_task = cert_task;
          this.cert_follow_on_task = cert_follow_on_task;
          this.sysapproval_group = sysapproval_group;
    


          this.TicketLineChartData.labels = monthYear;
          if (this.chartUpdatedOnce) {
            this.chart.update();
          }
        }
      });

I'm currently using TicketLineChartData to create the proper legend. However the only way I know how to map the legends to the dataset is to use the index, but I currently have no way to break down Other into roblem, problem_task, incident_task, u_incident_task, cert_task, cert_follow_on_task, sysapproval_group without making their own Lines in the Line Chart.
    public TicketLineChartData: ChartData<"line"> = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
      { 
      data: [], 
      label: "Total"},
      { 
        data: [], 
        label: "Incidents",
      },
      { 
        data: [], 
        label: "Other",
      },
      { 
        data: [], 
        label: "Change Tasks",
        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
      },
  ],
  };

